# The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context In Dotnet 6 - VS Code

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

Im using VS Code and Dotnet 6.
I'm Getting ***The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context*** error while adding the following code in **Program.cs**.

(using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; is already added.)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(ServiceProvider => {
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDbSettings)).Get<MongoDbSettings>();
});
```

And also error at **=>** symbol as ***Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<IServiceProvider, IMongoClient>'***

Comment: Try builder.configuration